# Very hard variation of handshake problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

Here is the problem:

There are 1000 people in a hall. Initially one person had his hand painted. Every second everyone shakes their hand with someone else (in the sense that every second 500 couples form and the two people in the same couple shake hands with each other). In addition no two people can ever shake hands more than once. Of course whenever someone with a painted hand shakes the hand of someone who has it clean, it gets it painted. How much time, at most, is needed to paint all the hands? Prove it.
Clarification: we are only considering games that run the full length, i.e. the game has to be able to get to the last round after which all possible handshakes have occurred, no dead ends allowed. So the question is posed within the framework of such games.

My considerations:

I've tried pretty hard to get the answer for a general n people game, or even for this 1000 people game, but there really seems to be nothing helpful to prove it or even guess it or find it easily for large n, especially given the fact that I have manually bashed the first cases for n = 2,4,6,8,10,12 (the answers being 1,2,3,5,6,8 rounds respectively) which look to have no useful relationship whatsoever between eachother or with n. I think the greedy algorithm is optimal, but I haven't even bothered proving that, since it doesn't really help to find the answer to the problem and prove it, so at times I've just tried to assume it, but even then it didn't quite get me anywhere. Also I don't think there is some beautifully simple symmetry argument to get an answer here, because that should hopefully be reflected in the cases for the first few n, but maybe I am missing it, I couldn't think of anything of that kind.

What I am thinking now is that the answer might be some really complicated non closed form/non elementary function of n, or possibly some not even expressible function of n (this last statement in the sense that it's some function who's values for each given n are defined to be the ones given by such a game like this one, or some isomorphic problem, and there definitely are such kind of functions out there, so this could be a possibility). But if any of these last options I've given are correct, how could one possibly prove that?

Thank you very much for the help, I hope there is someone who can solve this.

Comment: Did you in vent this problem? What was the motivation? Or what was the source if it wasn't your invention?

Comment: I was told of a similar setting problem by a friend, which was supposedly an interview question, but it wasn't too clearly stated and it asked for a much easier question, namely the "at least" number of rounds scenario. So from there I formulated my own clearly stated well defined problem and changed the question, and then started thinking about it myself, since I thought it was interesting, until I started realizing it was hard and after quite a bit couldn't really make any new progress and started thinking the answer might be what I outline in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: In which case I don't think I would know how to tackle it.

Comment: At first glance the problem seemed well defined but now I have doubts. In each round they pair off to shake hands, and the same people can't shake hands twice.OK, suppose there are 6 people. The first round of handshakes goes AB, CD, EF, and the second tound goes AF, BC, DE. If the third round goes AD, BE, CF, then they've painted themselves into a corner, the fourth round is impossible. Is there a rule forbidding the people from pairing off in a way that makes it impossible to continue the process?

Comment: @bof I think additional rule is needed - all possible handshakes have to occur.

Comment: Well players have to play in a way such that the game goes to the end, in the sense that everyone has to be able to shake everyone's else's hand before the game is necessarily over after 999 (or in general n-1) rounds. So I am only considering game configurations that don't have rounds that lead to dead ends like the one you illustrated, that would not allow the game to potentially go the full length. Then the question is posed within the framework of such games. I guess that's not super explicit in the statement I have so I will probably edit it.

Comment: On the other hand, in your specific example, at the round in which the game must terminate, everyone has their hand painted, so even in a version of the problem in which  you considered games that lead to dead ends to be valid, I think it would be remarkable that after some n, you could prove that the answer is infinity, in the sense that  one could always construct games in which you get to a dead end before everyone has their hand painted. Maybe this could be branched off to a different question, I would be very interested in seeing a proof of this as well.

Comment: But maybe the two questions are kind of equivalent, in the sense that it's not possible ever to have a game reach a dead end before everyone is painted, not sure, or maybe just for particular n, and in that case what kind of n? This is definitely also interesting to explore, but again, here just focus on valid games as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: @Oldboy yeah basically that's it, I expand on that in my comments, but again the other question is also interesting and hard I think, do people think I should post it separately?

Comment: Your manual bashing result seems off; it is not hard to check that $8$ people can do it in $3$ rounds, and in general $2^k$ people can do it in $k$ rounds. In general I would suspect somewhere near $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ rounds, as this is the required number of rounds without the restriction that two people cannot shake hands twice.

Comment: You are wrong, or maybe you don't understand the question. The whole point is that you want to find AT MOST how many rounds you can go without having everyone get their hands painted, so sure for n = 8 you can make it in three rounds but that's useless, since that's at best how much it would take

Comment: Ah, I understand now, sorry for the mixup. Then a probably undesirable solution would be for the person that starts with a painted hand to use their other hand when shaking.

Comment: ahahahhahahaha yeah

Comment: i think there is no way to reach a dead end. After 999 round everyone has shoke hands with anyone, in particular with the first blue painted man, so in at most $n-1$ round the game end without any issure (if i got the point of your comments wrong please let me know)

Comment: @JayTuma an explicit example was given by bof a while ago.  After those three rounds a fourth round cannot be formed because three of the following pairs must be chosen: AE, DF, CE, BD, AC, BF, and there's no way to choose three of these pairs without selecting (at least) one person to be in two couples, (and at least another person to be in zero).

Comment: Has anyone made any progress?

Comment: I'm currently having some difficulty even finding a closed form solution for the number of distinct ways to partition $K_{2n}$ into $2n-1$ perfect matchings (up to two layers of permutations). Let alone using that to attack the problem itself.

Comment: I found the numbers I was looking for here: http://oeis.org/A000438  There does not seem to be a nice way to generate them.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity yeah I made similar considerations, and also consulted oeis multiple times, but clearly it's not pretty, it's just really hard. I wonder how one could prove what I state in the last paragraph in my question, which at his point I am pretty sure is the case.

Comment: @Gen could you provide an example for 5 rounds with n=8?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $2m(2n+1)$ people.  The following procedure allows $(2m-1)2n$ rounds before the last hands are painted.  In the best case of $n\approx m$, that is about $N-2\sqrt N$ rounds.
Divide the people into $2n+1$ groups of size $2m$.
In $2n$ mega-rounds of $2m-1$ rounds each, one group handshakes people in its own group, and the other groups are paired off.
Label groups from $0$ to $2n$.  Suppose the painted hand is in Group $0$, and the last clean hand in Group $2n$. In mega-round $k$, group $g$ shakes hands with group $2n+k-g\pmod{2n+1}$.   The dirty hands after $k$ megarounds are groups $0$ to $k-1$, and group $2n$ shakes group $k$ in round $k$.
For $1000=25×40$, that puts some hands remaining clean after $936$ rounds.
This can be applied to $2m(2n+1)+2p$, with $p$ of the groups being $2m+2$. Their megarounds are length $2m$ instead of $2m-1$, so the total clean rounds is $(2m-1)2n+p\ge N-2m-4n+1$. That puts a lower bound of $N-\sqrt{8N}+1$ by this method.

Comment: Why did you put this as an answer? This is not anywhere near a solution. What you did is show an easy lower bound on the answer, which is already off from the actual solution, for example in the case n = 10, where you can go 6 rounds, not 5.

Comment: Because he's sharing his progress on the problem, and it's too much for a comment.  This is allowed and encouraged by the site rules.